# XGBRegressor: change random_state no effect

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost

the `xgboost.XGBRegressor` seems to produce the same results despite the fact a new random seed is given.

According to the `xgboost` documentation [`xgboost.XGBRegressor`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn):

> seed : int Random number seed. (Deprecated, please use random_state)
>
> random_state : int Random number seed. (replaces seed)

`random_state` is the one to be used, however, no matter what `random_state` or `seed` I use, the model produce the same results. A Bug?

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

def xgb_train_predict(random_state=0, seed=None):
    X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)
    xgb = XGBRegressor(random_state=random_state, seed=seed)
    xgb.fit(X, y)
    y_ = xgb.predict(X)
    return y_

check = xgb_train_predict()

random_state = [1, 42, 58, 69, 72]
seed = [None, 2, 24, 85, 96]

for r, s in product(random_state, seed):
    y_ = xgb_train_predict(r, s)
    assert np.equal(y_, check).all()
    print('CHECK! \t random_state: {} \t seed: {}'.format(r, s))

[Out]:
    CHECK!   random_state: 1     seed: None
    CHECK!   random_state: 1     seed: 2
    CHECK!   random_state: 1     seed: 24
    CHECK!   random_state: 1     seed: 85
    CHECK!   random_state: 1     seed: 96
    CHECK!   random_state: 42    seed: None
    CHECK!   random_state: 42    seed: 2
    CHECK!   random_state: 42    seed: 24
    CHECK!   random_state: 42    seed: 85
    CHECK!   random_state: 42    seed: 96
    CHECK!   random_state: 58    seed: None
    CHECK!   random_state: 58    seed: 2
    CHECK!   random_state: 58    seed: 24
    CHECK!   random_state: 58    seed: 85
    CHECK!   random_state: 58    seed: 96
    CHECK!   random_state: 69    seed: None
    CHECK!   random_state: 69    seed: 2
    CHECK!   random_state: 69    seed: 24
    CHECK!   random_state: 69    seed: 85
    CHECK!   random_state: 69    seed: 96
    CHECK!   random_state: 72    seed: None
    CHECK!   random_state: 72    seed: 2
    CHECK!   random_state: 72    seed: 24
    CHECK!   random_state: 72    seed: 85
    CHECK!   random_state: 72    seed: 96
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems (I didn't know it myself before starting to dig for an answer :) ), that xgboost uses random generator only for sub-sampling, see [this Laurae's comment on a similar github issue](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2636#issuecomment-324975410). And otherwise behavior is deterministic.

If you would have used sampling, there is an issue in the `seed`/`random_state` handling by the current sklearn API in xgboost. `seed` is indeed claimed to be deprecated, but it seems that if one provides it, it will still be used over `random_state`, as can be seen [here in the code](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/b018ef104f0c24efaedfbc896986ad3ed1b66774/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py#L196-L202). This comment is relevant only when you have `seed not None`

Comment: Thanks, it's easy to overlook the default `subsample=1` argument.

Comment: Would you elaborate on the fix. I'm not able to get reproducible results from XGBoost, even by setting `seed`, `random_state` or `colsample_bytree`

Comment: What xgb version do you have? The code from OP adding `subsampling` yields fully reproducible predictions in xgb 0.90, when one uses `random_state`

Answer (score 0):

Tested with xgboost-1.6.1
Setting only `random_state` worked.

When reading `X` and `y` from the data source. Please make sure they are in the same order and with the same decimal values.

The following example is using `pd.DataFrame`

```
round_value = ..
my_seed = ...

X = round(X, round_value)
X = X[sorted(X)]

y = round(y, round_value)
y = y[sorted(y)]

X_train = X....
y_train = y....

X_test = X....

xgb_model = XGBRegressor(random_state=my_seed)
xgb_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
xgb_pred = xgb_model.predict(X_test)
```