# How to get average Accuracy Score for multiple runs in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, metrics

I trained the XGBClassifier model and got accuracy score for test data:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
model_xgbc=XGBClassifier(n_estimators=1000, max_depth=2,learning_rate=0.02)
model_xgbc.fit(xtrain,ytrain)
predictions=model_xgbc.predict(xtest)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
test_accuracy=accuracy_score(predictions,ytest)
print(f'Accuracy Score is {test_accuracy}')
```

[image]

Every time I restart the kernel, I get different accuracy score, but close to this one.
If I wanted to get an average accuracy score for 10 runs, I would restart the kernel for 10 times and divide the sum of the different accuracy scores by 10. Can I do it different way without restarting for multiple times?

Comment: Often these libraries there is a random seed argument you could plug in, but this answer suggests it doesn't quite work that way with this package: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50797002/xgbregressor-change-random-state-no-effect

Comment: Arguably, you do not need to restart the kernel; merely *re-running* `XGBClassifier()` would give different results, so you could easily construct a loop, even without messing explicitly with the random seed.

Comment: This sees like more of a machine learning question than a programming question. You should ask on Cross Validated. FWIW, my opinion is that you probably aren't as interested in the variance of the score with respect to random initialization as you are in the variance with respect to different datasets -- that's what cross validation aims to describe. So I would stick to that approach.